# Dojo Calendar: Is there a way to set my own holidays?

Tags: javascript, dojo, calendar

I want to program my own holidays into the dojox calendar widget. Currently it only shows the weekends and such in a different color. I want to do this for special, local holidays as well but I don't see any way to do it.

I can program the holidays as full-day events but I was hoping for something more elegant. Is there anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by subclassing views and override SimpleColumnView.styleGridColumn MatrixView.styleGridCell methods (you have an example of usage of subclassed view there: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#view-management).

As this is not trivial, in Dojo 1.9 (which is currently in Beta), the custom styling of grid cells was improved (with no override) see doc with examples: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/calendar#grid-cell-styling

Hope this helps,

Damien